# Django CMS Plugin: How to store combo setting and retrieve on setting window load?

Tags: django, django-cms

First of all pardon my ignorance as I am kind of new into it.

[image]

I have been able to show a Dropdown list in *Settings* Window that fetches data from Db. Now I want to select some value, save and on re-opening of setting modal window I wanna show selected field. So far I figured out that CMS Plugin model actually appears on setting modal window. Below are details

**models.py**

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

class SurveyPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    name = models.CharField("Survey Name", max_length=255, default='Survey Name',
                            help_text='Enter Survey Name')
    description = models.CharField("Survey Description", max_length=500, blank=True, help_text='Write Description here')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Returning some Survey Text"
```

**forms.py**

from django import forms
from src.survey.models import Survey
from src.survey.models import SurveyPluginModel

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    all_surveys = Survey.objects.only('name')
    surveys = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=all_surveys)

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyPluginModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now if I add a model field in `SurveyPluginModel` it instantly appears on screen. What I want to save `surveys = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=all_surveys)` selected value to place where other plugin setting is stored and next time it makes it selected. What I guess `instance` is not going to help, the Plugin model field should be helpful but then I am not able to make a link with form field.

Please guide.